# JDBC Connection Pool Issue

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm experiencing an issue executing a sql query from within my java application; it's difficult to detect what the exact problem is until I get debugging going - there are no errors are returned

The only thing returned in the logs is some Connection Pool information along with my sql query - I've noticed the pool size is set to '0'

```
[2014-09-23 07:58:33,253] DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'DATA' to parameter: 1
[2014-09-23 07:58:33,253] DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'Y' to parameter: 2
[2014-09-23 07:58:33,255] DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProvider:129 - returning connection to pool, pool size: 1
[2014-09-23 07:58:33,256] DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProvider:93 - total checked-out connections: 0
[2014-09-23 07:58:33,257] DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProvider:99 - using pooled JDBC connection, pool size: 0
```

The exact same code is deployed on a separate application server and working properly (Specifically Weblogic - working vs. Tomcat - not working). The setup of the libraries is different between to the two, so from a high-level perspective:

- Could this be a driver error?
- Should a Connection Pool's size be set to "0"?

Comment: can you give further details e.g. how have you setup the connection pool in tomcat?

Comment: increase the connection pools? glassfish is default 32

Comment: This particular application is not utilizing hibernate, & I will update the pool information once I find it @IanLim